# How to make diagonal circle border gradient?

Tags: css, gradient, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I have a problem with CSS3. I don't know how to make a diagonal round gradient border like that:
[image: circle example]

I found something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/agusesetiyono/796XC/9/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=796XC):

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #eee;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

But unfortunately this works only with squares.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm...you want a conical gradient I think...they're not here yet. I'd use an SVG here I think.

Comment: Ugh. Ok thanks, but is it the only way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this i have used a pseudo element with -ve `z-index`

Note: the background is not transparent as i have used a `background-color` for inner element

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #7B73A4 0%, #150E5E 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: transparent background instead of white background?

Answer (score 11):

Conical gradient is a gradient which goes along the circular arc around a center. This is what we see in color wheels. As Paulie_D had noted, these are currently not possible with CSS but [Lea Verou has developed a polyfill for it](https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/).

Having said that, what you are looking for **doesn't seem to be a conical gradient**, it is normal angled linear gradient but applied only to the borders. 
This cannot be achieved through CSS `border-image` property because of how it is intended to work as per [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping).

> A box's backgrounds, but not its border-image, are clipped to the appropriate curve

---

If the center portion of the circle is a solid color then the approach mentioned in Vitorino's answer can be used. If it is not a solid color (that is, the page background is a gradient or an image which needs to show through) then it would not help. The following approaches can be used for that case.

**Using Mask Image:**

This approach uses a circular mask image to mask the inner portion of the circle. This makes it look as though only the border has the gradient applied to it. The **drawback** is that this feature is currently supported **only in Webkit powered browsers**.

```css
.border-gradient-mask {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #7B73A4 0%, #150E5E 100%);
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 57%, white 58%);
  mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 57%, white 58%);
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, sandybrown, chocolate);
}
```

```html
<div class="border-gradient-mask"></div>
```

---

**Using SVG Shape or Mask:**

The other approach is to use SVG `circle` element to create the circle and then assign the gradient to the `stroke` property. The gradient also has a `gradientTransform` applied to it because that is the only way to produce angled linear gradients with SVG.

```css
.border-gradient-svg {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.border-gradient-svg svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.border-gradient-svg circle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: url(#grad);
  stroke-width: 8;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, sandybrown, chocolate);
}
```

```html
<div class="border-gradient-svg">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="rotate(135 0.5 0.5)">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7B73A4" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#150E5E" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle r="46" cx="50" cy="50" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

The same can be achieved by using SVG `mask` also. All that is needed is to create a mask with two `circle` elements, fill the larger circle with white, smaller circle with black and then apply the mask to our original `circle` element. The area occupied by smaller circle (with black fill) will be transparent.

```css
.border-gradient-svg {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.border-gradient-svg svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.border-gradient-svg .grad-border {
  fill: url(#grad);
  mask: url(#masker);
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, sandybrown, chocolate);
}
```

```html
<div class="border-gradient-svg">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="rotate(135 0.5 0.5)">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7B73A4" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#150E5E" />
      </linearGradient>
      <mask id="masker" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">
        <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#fff" />
        <circle r="42" cx="50" cy="50" fill="#000" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" class="grad-border"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

**Using Clip Path:**

Another approach to creating this would be to use a `clip-path` (with inline SVG) with [`clip-rule` set to `evenodd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#ClipRuleProperty). **Advantage** of clip path solution over the others is that this will trigger hover effects only while hovering on filled area (and not the transparent area). The **drawback** is that IE doesn't support clip paths (even with SVG).

```css
.border-gradient-clip {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #7B73A4 0%, #150E5E 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, sandybrown, chocolate);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0,0.5 a0.5,0.5 0 1,0 1,0 a0.5,0.5 0 1,0 -1,0z M0.08,0.5 a0.42,0.42 0 1,0 0.84,0 a0.42,0.42 0 1,0 -0.84,0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="border-gradient-clip"></div>
```