# Border gradient from once color to another uing css

Tags: css

Can i create a nice border gradient effect from #7487ad to #c284a2 using css or javascript ?

I need the following ones:

[image]

AND

[image]

Comment: almost similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582563/how-to-make-diagonal-circle-border-gradient/34584728